# Typescript: How to dynamically infer type of the exported default module to an Object

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a redux store which looks like this

```
store
 --index.ts
 --utils.ts
 --modules
    --user.ts
```

Now, in my root store `index.ts`, I configure a `redux store` like below

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import { updateModules } from "./utils";

const modules = {};
updateModules(modules);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    ...modules // this is to auto import modules and put it here
    // user: user
  }
});

export default store;

// Type of store.getState get lost cuz of dynamically adding modules
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

**utils.ts:**

```
import { camelize } from "utils/string-util";
import { LoseObject } from "./types";

export const updateModules = (modules: LoseObject): void => {
  // Allow us to dynamically require all redux module files.
  const requireModule = require.context(
    // Search for files in the current directory.
    "./modules",
    // Search for files in subdirectories.
    true,
    // Include any .ts files that are not types file or a unit test.
    /^((?!types|\.unit\.).)*\.ts$/
  );
  requireModule.keys().forEach((fileName) => {
    const moduleName = camelize(fileName.split("/")[1]);
    /**
     * I want to put the type of exported default type to each of these modules dynamically
    */
    modules[moduleName] = requireModule(fileName).default;
  });
};
```

**Problem:**
If I do not use the utility and manually add each module to store, it provides a each module state type such as `IUserState` or any module I have provided to state. But if i dynamically do this, and spread dynamically created `object` of these modules, it looses it's `type`. I need help to infer the received default type to each of the modules, which then get registered to store.

SandBox Link - https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-sara-wscq2?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in TypeScript. Your best bet is to automatically generate the code, but end up with a fixed `.ts` file in the end. This is the way most frameworks solve this problem.

Comment: Good to see @redux/toolkit maintainer actively supporting questions. Thanks. I need to go manual way to utilise the types